# Datepicker jQuery, strange when i write directly in the input

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have something strange with jQuery datepicker.

If i choose a date with datepicker, it's ok, no problem.

But if i write a date directly in the input, for example : `19/05/1990` (french format)

When i write the first number of the year (here 1), jquery select automaticaly the date `2001` in my datepicker and remove the value on my input....

Do you have an idea ?

Edit : Here, all options i use

```
yearRange: "-113:+0",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                closeText: 'Fermer',
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                prevText: '&#x3c;Préc',
                nextText: 'Suiv&#x3e;',
                currentText: 'Courant',
                monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
                'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fév','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun',
                'Jul','Aoû','Sep','Oct','Nov','Déc'],
                dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dim','Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Di','Lu','Ma','Me','Je','Ve','Sa']
```

Comment: could you provide a sample link?

Comment: I tried your configuration and it's working fine, if I write "1" for the year the datepicker goes to 2001, but it doesn't delete the input. Ckeck http://jsfiddle.net/ZfpQ6/

Comment: Is it possible to disable that ?

Comment: I'm afraid that the plugin doesn't have any option to disable that behaviour. You will have to change the source code of the plugin

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct localization when you instantiate the `datepicker()` function.

Please see the [localization documentation and example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization) or the "Localization" section of [datepicker's API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) (which specifically suggests using `jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js`).

```
$( selector ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

Please see a [working example of the `datepicker()` "localized" for France at http://jsfiddle.net/ZfpQ6/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfpQ6/4/)

Comment: Just FYI ("PVI", en francais?): this similar question also addresses localization: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11571557/1430996

Comment: Did you include the 'jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js' file? See http://jsfiddle.net/ZfpQ6/4/  ...when I type "19/05/1990" into the field it selects the correct date...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the jump to 2001 when you type 1 for the year you can override the behaviour of the plugin overriding the function `_doKeyUp` before create your instance.

```
var oldKeyUp = $.datepicker._doKeyUp;

$.datepicker._doKeyUp = function(event){
    var inst = $.datepicker._getInst(event.target);
    var tmpValue = inst.input.val();
    var arr = tmpValue.split('/');
    if (arr.length == 3){
        if (arr[2].length == 4){
            return oldKeyUp(event);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({...});
```

With this the plugin will wait until you have the full 4 digits of the year (assuming the format "dd/mm/yy").